# Amcharts Maps, how to set and get id of MapPolygonSeries?

Tags: amcharts

I want to get the ID of an MapPolygonSeries so I know which element was clicked on.

My goal is to represent the selected country (in a map) on a dropdown.

Currently I have the following code for zooming to a map area on click.

```
// Zooming to map area on click
polygonTemplate.events.on("hit", (ev) => {
  ev.target.series.chart.zoomToMapObject(ev.target, this.COUNTRY_ZOOM);
  // How to get the ID of the of the map object here? ev.id?
  this.handleCountrySelection();
});
```

For creating the polygon series I use the am4geodata_worldHigh with

```
useGeodata = true
```

from the chart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear what you mean by the ID of a MapPolygonSeries.

If you want to provide your own way to identify a MapPolygonSeries, you can assign a string to [its `name` property](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/mappolygonseries/#name_property).

With `useGeodata = true`, an ISO2 ID and name will be provided to each MapPolygon *within* a series from amCharts' geojson. So if you're looking for the country's ID/name when a user clicks it, this can be found via a mapPolygon's `dataItem.dataContext`, in your event handler that would look like `ev.target.dataItem.dataContext`, e.g.:

```
// identify a series by its name
polygonSeries.name = "worldSeries";

// Zooming to map area on click
polygonTemplate.events.on("hit", (ev) => {
  ev.target.series.chart.zoomToMapObject(ev.target, this.COUNTRY_ZOOM);
  // How to get the ID of the of the map object here? ev.id?
  console.log("Series name: ", ev.target.series.name);
  console.log("Country ISO2 id: ", ev.target.dataItem.dataContext.id);
  console.log("Country ISO2 name: ", ev.target.dataItem.dataContext.name);
  this.handleCountrySelection();
});
```

Simple demo with all that thrown together:
https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/e3fd144dcf886d29d27b7f47df73f565/?editors=1111